# Is it OK to have Many to Many relationships in Core Data?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, database-design, many-to-many

Say I have a model where an `Employee` can have many `Bosses` (life is tough) and a `Boss` can have many `Employees`.

I have a Many to Many relationship that goes both ways. Is this acceptable in Core Data? Is this against the 5 normal forms of database design?

In a nutshel, may I go ahead and create this relationship or will it cause me trouble in the future?

Answer (score 4):

Apple address this issue in their [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10), under the heading *Many to Many Relationships*. Having introduced the topic, the guide reassures nervous users with the following:

> If you have a background in database management and this [many-to-many relationships] causes you concern, don't worry: if you use a SQLite store, Core Data automatically creates the intermediate join table for you.

In other words, by allowing many-to-many relationships Core Data isn't doing anything that violates established database logic, it's simply handling that logic for you.

Comment: I would add that, if you want to define attributes for the relationship (such as the date that the boss became the employee's boss), then you do have to create the intermediate entity yourself in order to model those attributes.  So you might have `Boss <--->> Employment <<---> Employee` rather than `Boss <<--->> Employee`.